# How do I solve the "Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate" error problem?

Tags: swift

I made a function for drawing a graph and this error came up when creating points.

```
func drawChart(with data: [WAChartsView.Data], topChartOffset: Int) {
    guard let maxValue = data.sorted(by: { $0.value > $1.value }).first?.value else { return }
    let valuePoints = data.enumerated().map { CGPoint(x: CGFloat($0), y: CGFloat($1.value)) }
    let chartHeight = bounds.height / CGFloat(maxValue + topChartOffset)

    let points = valuePoints.map {
        let x = bounds.width / CGFloat(valuePoints.count - 1) * $0.x //cgfl
        let y = bounds.height - $0.y * chartHeight
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
```

The problem comes out after the line `let points = valuePoints.map {`.

I found the same problems on the Internet, but they were mainly for SwiftUI.

Comment: This generally means the compiler can't infer the type resulting from an expression; usually because of an error or typo that is making it impossible to resolve the expression to a single type.  Break expressions down or explicitly declare variable types to help the compiler understand what's expected and then it will generate more helpful error messages.  I expect your enumerated data point isn't what you believe it to be.

Comment: `let points: [CGPoint] = `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `let points = valuePoints.map {...}` is mapping from your source array, `valuePoints`, to a new array. The compiler can't infer the type of the new array. I see this when the compiler can't infer the return type of a closure (which is what's happening here.)

Leo told you what to do: Declare the type of `points` explicitly:

```
let points: [CGPoint] = valuePoints.map {...}
```

As Flanker says, the compiler will also generate this error when there is something else wrong with your code and it gets confused. Try the above and see what happens. (I don't see any other errors, but I also don't know the types of all the variables your code is using.)

Comment: Maybe OP also needs to coerce the `CGPoint` `x` property from `Double` to `CGFloat` `CGFloat($0.x)`. Or even better coerce it all to `Double` instead

Comment: The ambiguity is probably due to the fact that CGFloat native type sometimes is Float sometimes is Double